# Configuration changes in dropwizard application to work with react browserHistory

Tags: java, react-router, react-redux, dropwizard, browser-history

I have a `react` app running on a `dropwizard` server. The `bundle.js` is served on /ui. When I open the url on /ui and navigate the app(and goto /ui/content), it works fine. But when I try to refresh a specific page like /app/content, it gives a `404`.

I know about client side rendering and server side rendering and also that I need to do a `GET` call for /ui and route the rest on client side, but I couldn't find any documentation for how to do it in `dropwizard`.

I also know using `hashHistory` in place of `browserHistory`  will work(as the hash part of the url is not sent to the server), but I wanted to know if this can be done with browserHistory.

There is documentation on how to configure an `express` sever but I could not find anything for a `jetty/dropwizard`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the Dropwizard level, one thing you can use a use servlet filter to rewrite the URL. One popular implementation is the [Tucky UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). You would implement it as follows:

1. Register the filter with Dropwizard:

   ```
   @Override
   public void run(ExampleConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
       FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = environment.servlets()
               .addFilter("UrlRewriteFilter", new UrlRewriteFilter());
       registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
       registration.setInitParameter("confPath", "urlrewrite.xml");
   }
   ```
2. Add the `urlrewrite.xml` configuration file to your `src/main/resources`, adding a rewrite rule

   ```
   <urlrewrite>
       <rule>
           <from>^/(?!(api|static/|manifest\.json|assets-manifest\.json|favicon\.ico)).*$</from>
           <to type="forward">/index.html</to>
       </rule>
   </urlrewrite>
   ```

   The above rule states that if the request path matches the above regex, then forward the request to the `index.html` file. What I used to test was the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), where the output is a few of those files listed in the matcher. Those files should not be forward.

   The regex uses a negative lookahead, so it's like a negation. It may look like I'm saying that if the path matches those files, then forward, but it's actually the opposite. If you are not using the create-react-app, then your regex will look different. The point is to negate the files you don't want forwarded.

I put together a working demo. Check out the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/psamsotha/dropwizard-react-urlrewrite).

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Is there a way that I can get this from app.yml rather than a configuration file?

Comment: Not that I can think of.