# Serving React with DropWizard where there are React-Routers?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, react-router, dropwizard

In my App.js:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <div className="App-body">
            <Route
              exact path='/set/employees'
              render={(props) => (
                ...
              )}
            />
            <Route
              exact path='/set/om'
              render={(props) => (
                ...
              )}
            />
            <Route
              exact path='/set/legal'
              render={(props) => (
                ...
              )}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

In the Application class for my DropWizard project:

```
  public void initialize(final Bootstrap<lspireConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/build/", "/"));

    }
```

As you can see, I'm serving at localhost:8080/index.html, which renders the App.js page. However, I want to implement with React-Router so if I go to the path I set in a Route i.e. /set/legal, it would render those components inside. Not sure how to accomplish that and what routes I'd even be hitting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuration changes in dropwizard application to work with react browserHistory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45560374/configuration-changes-in-dropwizard-application-to-work-with-react-browserhistor)